# React native white blank screen when load website in a webview

Tags: android, react-native, webview

**Bug description:** The site that I directed with Webview is opened in the ios simulator, Although not working in the andorid simulator.

**To Reproduce:**
`react-native init AwesomeProject`
`cd AwesomeProject`
`react-native run-android`

`&& my code`

[code](https://gist.github.com/cemthecebi/9e42a5ff21b3c6e2fcd96134eb794c65)

**Expected behavior:**.  Work same as ios simulator

**Screenshots/Videos:**
[image: Screen Shot 2020-06-01 at 01 21 55]
[image: Screen Shot 2020-06-01 at 01 22 16]

**Environment:**
 - OS: macOS 
 - OS version: 10.15.3
 - react-native version: 0.62.2 
 - react-native-webview version: 10.2.3

Comment: Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a styles problem, try the following

```
<View style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#FFF'}}>
  ...//webview component
</View>
```

Comment: Sorry, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

there are several solutions that I found for myself. @mlammert

add this [code](https://gist.github.com/cemthecebi/c2bf6ad64afa0f0816b386f1c3d88842) snippet to

`\node_modules\react-native webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java`

After that  in `AndroidManifest.xml` add these code snippets.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

and in the  add this one `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">`